# Extracting relative paths from absolute paths

Tags: java, relative-path, filepath, string-parsing, code-cleanup

This is a seemingly simple problem but I am having trouble doing it in a clean manner. I have a file path as follows:

/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location/of/my/file

What I need is to extract /of/my/file from the above given path since that is my relative path.

The way I am thinking of doing it is as follows:

```
String absolutePath = "/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location/of/my/file";
String[] tokenizedPaths = absolutePath.split("/");
int strLength = tokenizedPaths.length;
String myRelativePathStructure = (new StringBuffer()).append(tokenizedPaths[strLength-3]).append("/").append(tokenizedPaths[strLength-2]).append("/").append(tokenizedPaths[strLength-1]).toString();
```

This will probably serve my immediate needs but can somebody suggest a better way of extracting sub-paths from a provided path in java?

Thanks

Comment: You have to either know what the root path looks like or what the "child" path looks like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

```
URI base = URI.create("/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location");
URI absolute =URI.create("/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location/of/my/file");
URI relative = base.relativize(absolute);
```

This will result in `of/my/file`.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a way to have more control over what to relativize. Would it be possible to somehow grab /the/location/of/my/file in a similar elegant manner?

Comment: @sc_ray - yes, change your base URI.

Comment: @sc_ray Have a look at `File`'s [getParentFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) method. `File` contains methods for converting to/from `URI` instances. Java 7 users _might_ be able to use the `Path` type in the [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package - I haven't looked at it in any depth.

Answer (score 1):

With pure string operations and assuming you know the base path and assuming you only want relative paths below the base path and never prepend a "../" series:

```
String basePath = "/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location/";
String absolutePath = "/this/is/an/absolute/path/to/the/location/of/my/file";
if (absolutePath.startsWith(basePath)) {
    relativePath = absolutePath.substring(basePath.length());
}
```

There are surely better ways to do this with classes that are aware of path logic, such as `File` or `URI`, though. :)