# Find relative path based on absolute path

Tags: java, path

In my `maven` project, i need to address sqlite class which is located in `resources/db`

I have a db in the absolute path like:

```
C:/Users/Salman/Desktop/Courses/Thesis/Code/ADTool2-master/project/src/main/resources/db/smartADTool.sqlite
```

and the class file which needs this file is:

```
C:/Users/Salman/Desktop/Courses/Thesis/Code/ADTool2-master/project/src/main/java/ee/ut/smarttool/DB/DB.java
```

to extract the relative path I used the following relative address:

```
../../../../../resources/db/smartADTool.sqlite
```

but it seems that i the **db is not located there.**

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9826900/4248342)?

Comment: Since it is in the same project, You can refer it using db/smartADTool.sqlite, Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is in the same project, You can refer it using

> db/smartADTool.sqlite

Example -

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("db/smartADTool.sqlite").getFile());
```